# Why is the negative sign printing before the $ sign?

Tags: java, string

I am supposed to add a toString method to the banckAccount class.

It should return a name separated by a comma and a space. `Ex: "Yana"` and balance of `3.03` , the call `yana.toString()` should return the string `"Yana, $3.03"`.

I tried to add:

```
public String toString() {
    return  name + ", " + "$"+ balance;
}
```

It works when I type in:

```
"user, $90.01"
```

But when I enter

```
"Bankrupt Government, -$765432.10"
```

I keep getting:

```
 "Bankrupt Government, $-765432.1"
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BankAccount {

     String name;
     double balance;

     public void deposit (double amount ){
          balance = balance + amount;


     }

     public void withdraw ( double amount) {
          balance = balance - amount ;          
     }

  }//end of class
```

Comment: Where are you performing input?

Answer (score 3):

Your balance is negative so it prints as listed. It needs to be

```
if(balance < 0){
   balance = balance * -1;
   return  name + ", " + "-$"+ balance;
}
else{
  return  name + ", " + "$"+ balance;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is right here:

```
return  name + ", " + "$"+ balance;
```

Java simply concatenates the string as you have defined it. So if `balance` is a negative number, you will get `$`, followed by a negative number.

If you want it to display the `-` in the proper place, you can do something like this:

```
String sign = (balance < 0) ? "-" : "";
System.out.println(name + ", " + sign + "$" + Math.abs(balance));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite obvious, what your method toString() is doing. If balance is negative, it is just added to the string with "-" sign after the "$". I would detect, if the balance is positive or not:

`private String toString() {
        if (balance > 0.0) {
            return name + ", " + "$" + balance;
        } else {
            return name + ", -$" + (balance * (-1));
        }
}`

Or

`private String toString() {
        return name + ", " + 
               balance > 0.0 ? ("$" + balance) : ("-$" + (balance * (-1)));
}`

Answer (score 0):

## hope this helps run this program

```
      import java.util.*;
      import java.io.*;
      public class HelloWorld{
      public String toString() {
        if(balance<0)
        {
            balance= Math.abs(balance);
             return  name + ", " +"-"+ "$"+ balance;
        }else
        {
    return  name + ", " + "$"+ balance;
        }
}
       String name="sachin";
     double balance=-1000.00;
 public void deposit (double amount ){
          balance = balance + amount;


     }
      public void withdraw ( double amount) {
          balance = balance - amount ;          
     }
     public static void main(String []args){
       // System.out.println("Hello World");

            HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

         System.out.println(helloWorld.toString());

     }
}
```